# how to print the index number of elements in the ArrayList using for each looping

Tags: java, list

Can anybody tell me how to print the index number of elements in the ArrayList using for each looping in Java.

Comment: Yes, someone can.

Comment: I expect your teacher hopes you can :-)

Comment: @Raedwald - If a teacher was asking for this rather than asking them to write a regular for loop, I'd fire the teacher.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc: Your statement has a huge philosophical implication. Assuming you don't know anything about others, **you** are the only one how can answer the question :D

Comment: @Felix King:  And yet, at the time I'm typing this response, 3 people have attempted an answer.  My statement was more of an emotional response than a philosophical response.  Besides, the answer is int noe = al.size();

Answer (score 8):

By keeping a separate index count:

```
int index=0;
for(String s : list){
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(index++)+": "+s);
}
```

Probably makes more sense to use a regular for loop instead. The "enhanced for loop" is based on the `Iterable` and `Iterator` interfaces - it doesn't know anything about implementation details of the underlying collection (which may well not *have* an index for each element).

Comment: You may want to increment the index somewhere as well. But agreed, a regular loop would be a better fit here.

Comment: You forgot to iterate the index

Comment: Actually, here i am looping as well as checking certain conditins, where i am trying to print sth when the condition is satisfied with the index number. But i tried and all the answers are not working.

Comment: is the method valueOf() is inbuilt method for String? if it is then tell me what method i can use normally instead of String object?

Answer (score 3):

like @Michael's but shorter. A pet obsession I'll admit.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("zero", "one", "two", "three");
int index=0;
for(String s : list)
    System.out.println((index++)+": "+s);
```

prints

```
0: zero
1: one
2: two
3: three
```

Comment: Keyboard to chair interface failure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was able to figure out the solution after certain manipulation to your answer passed to me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep track of the index numbers *yourself*, as you loop through the ArrayList. The List iterator won't do that for you.

You'd normally do that through a separate variable. You *could* store objects with an associated index, but you'd have to be sure to maintain ordering (by not deleting, resorting etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to either iterate with an integer index, or keep a counter going.

```
List<kind> aList;
...
int index = 0;
for(kind x  :  aList)
{
   ...
   index++;
}
```

or

```
for(int index = 0; index < aList.size(); index++)
{
    Kind x = aList.get(index)
...
}
```

Comment: (and it bugs me that y'have to do this! but so.)

Comment: I tried your first syntax in reference to for each looping but its not working. So what do you think may be the problem?

Comment: Keyboard to chair interface failure.